# Can I get a upright theta (θ) in pyplot by using the rc library's latex function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, rc

I am plotting XRD results in python. I want to use the graphs in an article. My x-axis lable is 2θ. I am using the *rc* library from matplotlib, which allows me to use latex in the lables, as well as to change the font to serif.

When I do use the normal theta command in latex, *i.e.* r'$\theta$', I get the theta on my lable, bit it is italicised, as it should be. I want the upright theta however, but the latex command for this, *i.e.* r'$\uptheta$', does not work. Nor does r'$\mathrm{\theta}$' or similar workarounds.

Is there any way to get an upright theta on my x-axis?

Attached is the relevant code with an image of the graph I get.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import rc
rc("text", usetex=True)
rc("font", family="serif")
sketsverhouding = 4 / 5
vol = 5, 5*sketsverhouding
half = 3, 3*sketsverhouding
derde = 2.3, 2.3*sketsverhouding

data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\pivde\Desktop\Tuks\nagraads\karakterisering\xrd\sifeksp_filament.xlsx", sheet_name = "python_data")
data.head()

def skets(y, etiket):
    pp.figure(figsize=half)
    pp.plot(data['2theta'], data[y], 'k-')
    pp.xlabel(r'2$\theta$ [$^\circ$]')
    pp.ylabel('Intensity')
    pp.tight_layout()
    pp.ylim(0, 15000)
    pp.savefig(naam.format(etiket))

naam = 'grafieke/xrd_sifekpsfil_{:03.0f}ldh_pla.svg'
skets('n', 0)
skets('t', 2)
```

[image: The graph output for skets('n', 0). Note that the theta is italicised and not upright.]

Comment: `plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{2\\theta }$' + ' ' + '$[^\circ]$', fontsize=20)`

Comment: That still has the theta in italics on my side?

Comment: Delete the codes : `from matplotlib import rc
rc("text", usetex=True)
rc("font", family="serif")`

Comment: OK, that works. Thank you. The only problem is that I need to have a serif font because the figures have to go into an article with a serif font.